# Including Drupal taxonomy term links in a twig template

Tags: drupal, twig, taxonomy

I am trying to put some Drupal taxonomy links into a twig template, but have hit a wall, hoping someone can help me out.

Here is the setup, and what I have tried so far...

I have a taxonomy vocabulary called "FAQ Category". Inside of it, there are several terms, for example, one of them is named "The Basics".

I also have a Drupal twig template named `views-view--faqs.html.twig`, which is displaying all the FAQ content types that have been tagged for a particular term. (...as a side question, I do not see a Drupal view that has been setup for this, so I dont know how `views-view--faqs.html.twig` is even working in the first place, but it is...)

What I need, is to have a simple navigation to each of the taxonomy terms on that template, but I dont know how to do it. I have tried things like:

```
{{ node.field_basics.value }}
{{ node.field_faq-category.entity.label }}
{{ content.faq_category.0.value }}
```

...but nothing is working. I am guessing there is a very simple solution, if anyone can help it would be much appreciated. This site was not developed by me, so I am doing a bit a reverse engineering.

If there is any more info you need to help get an answer, just let me know, I will provide as much info as I can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at the following guide:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates

Here you can learn how to output values or even reading field keys.

I believe you should try either:

```
{{ node.field_basics.0.uri }}
```

or

```
{{ content.faq_category.0.uri }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried both those, and unfortunatley they did not work. I have read about turning on debugging, but I cannot do that due to some very tight security on the services.yml file (although I am trying to get that resolved).

Any other ideas on the correct twig code to pull in taxonomy terms?